# Proving the absolute value of a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that if the sequence $\,\{a_n\}\,$ converges to $A$, then $\,\{|a_n\}|\,$ converges to |A|.  Also, is the converse true?

Comment: The second $\,A\,$ must be $\,|A|\,$ ...

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed it

Comment: [Hint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: @DavidMitra didn't even think to use that.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. (For your other question, think about sequences with alternating signs.)

Comment: The converse is not true: take $a_n=(-1)^n$ as a conterexample

Comment: @DavidMitra OK - so say I use an example of a sequence with alternating signs...do you think in an analysis class a proof would be necessary or simply justification that the converse is false?

Comment: A counterexample is what is needed. Show that your sequence satisfies $|x_n|\rightarrow |A|$ but $(x_n)$ does not converge to $A$. This will show that the converse is false.

Comment: @Student What is the difference between justification and proof? A justification that fails to prove, is not justifying ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\left||a_n|-|A|\right|\le|a_n-A|\ldots$$