# Concluding the convergence of a product of series

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $a(n)$ be a bounded sequence (not necessarily convergent) and assume $\lim b(n) = 0$.  Prove that $\lim a(n)b(n) = 0$.  Can we conclude anything about the convergence of $a(n)b(n)$ if $\lim b(n)=b$, where $b$ is not equal to $0$?

I know how to prove that first part, but in the convergence of $a(n)b(n)$, is there really anything you can definitively conclude since we don't know anything about $a(n)$ other than that it is bounded?

Comment: For the second part, think about the counterexample you used in your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302184/proving-the-absolute-value-of-a-sequence-converges). This should allow you to find an example where the product does not converge. Also, try to think of an example where the product does converge.

Comment: Please write your mathematics with LaTeX, to make them more readable. In the FAQ section you can find directions.

Comment: OK thanks I've been trying to find out how to do that since I've started asking.

Comment: @Student: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I'm working on it! Lol computers aren't my "strong-suit" ..thanks for that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

$$a_n:=(-1)^n\;\;,\;\;b_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Then

$$|a_n|\le 1\,\,\,\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,\,,\,\,b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

yet

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}$$

doesn't exist.

If instead the above bounded sequence you choose $\,a_n=k=\text{ constant}\,$ , then $\,a_nb_n\,$ does converge, so in general nothing can be said about the sequence $\,\{a_nb_n\}\,$